# How to display all buffer names in tabline?

Tags: buffers, statusline

How do I display the list of all buffers in the tabline? I am using the [lightline plugin](https://github.com/itchyny/lightline.vim), with the following settings in my `.vimrc`:

```
set showtabline=2
let g:lightline = { 'colorscheme': 'PaperColor' }
let g:lightline.tabline = {
            \ 'left': [ [ 'tabs' ] ],
            \ 'right': [ [ 'bufnum'] ] }
let g:lightline.separator = { 'left': '', 'right': '' }
let g:lightline.subseparator = {'left': '', 'right': '' }
```

I am only able to view one buffer name in the tabline at a time.

[image]

Swapping through the various buffers simply updates the name in the single available tab slot, like so:

[image]

Instead, I would like to display the buffer names simultaneously in the tabline, like the [vim-buftabline](https://github.com/ap/vim-buftabline) plugin does here:

[image]

Is there anyway I can achieve this without installing additional plugins? Is this a lightline issue or a vim issue, i.e. what do I need to add to my `.vimrc` to solve this? I've scoured the docs for lightline and vim (`:h setting-tabline`, etc.) and couldn't figure out how to display all the buffers.

Thanks for reading

Comment: why not installing a plugin? You can possibly achieve something similar with a custom function, but that will be close to using a plugin. BTW: the vim-airline statusline comes with a function for that out of the box

Comment: As @ChristianBrabandt said, use vim-buftabline if you want its functionalities. By the way, this is not usual way vim tabline is supposed to be used. But that's another issue, don't mind it now. Just use vim-buftabline

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Airline was causing this weird flickering issue whenever I resized my terminal window, but yeah it worked perfectly other than that. You're right about just using a plugin.  I eventually got everything working with https://github.com/mengelbrecht/lightline-bufferline

Comment: @klaus I tried using vim-buftabline, but it overrode lightline's tabline

Comment: So, your problem is fixed? And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26710166/11135136) is the usage of tabpages I mentioned. Take a look when you are more comfortable with Vim.

Comment: I am not sure what kind of flickering you are talking about (and I don't remember any issue about this), but note, it is expected that the statusline and tabline has to be redrawn on resizes and I am pretty sure, lightline needs to do so as well to calculate the width of the changed sections correctly.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Yeah, I wasn't able to find anyone else that had the flickering issue; basically, the whole terminal window would flash, not just the status/tablines when redrawn. After trying out lightline, the problem disappeared.

Comment: @klaus Yup, everything works as desired. And thanks, that link is exactly what I was looking for to learn more!

Comment: @AisforAmbition, when terminal is redrawn, the whole terminal is redrawn, not just part of it. Maybe for some reason, airline needed more time to redraw, so you could notice the flash. Probably the reason is having a huge feature set, maybe.

Answer (score 2):

Try installing the [lightline-bufferline](https://github.com/mengelbrecht/lightline-bufferline) plugin.

The README constains instructions on how to show buffers in lighline.